# preventing a camera from getting stuck inside a mesh in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, camera

I've a 3rd person camera similar to Mario64. Currently, I'm working on  preventing the camera from getting stuck inside a mesh. The goal is to  move the camera overhead. This much trickier than I'd expected.

I've tried using a while loop but that crashes the game.
The current code I'm using does this:
https://youtu.be/-o1-LEb_MZM

The code:

```
public class VCThirdPersonCamera : MonoBehaviour 
{
    :
    :
    /// clipping variables
    /// use the camera's slider to determine defaultFOV
    public Vector3    cameraOffset = new Vector3(0,0.125f,-0.125f); //moves camera so player doesn't get clipped

    public float      fovDefault   = 60f;                           //the desired default field of view set by user
    public float      camTurnTime  = 0f;                            //use to compensate for the camera turning
    public float      headCamTimer = 1.5f;                          //how long should the camera stay overHead
    public float      fieldOfView  = 95.0f;                         //set when camera is overHead
    public bool       camOccluded  = false;                         //is the camera occluded
    public bool       clipped      = true;                          //used for clipping
    public Camera     _camera;
    public GameObject theCamera;

    private LayerMask   _mask;
    private RaycastHit  _hit;
    /// end occlusionHandlers

    private void Awake ()
    {
        :
        /// instantiate occlusion culling handler through bitSwitch
        _mask = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("clip") | 0 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("clipNone");
    }

    private void LateUpdate ()
    {
        Vector3 targetCenter = _target.position + centerOffset;
        Vector3 targetHead = _target.position + headOffset;

        Vector3 theTarget = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward)* 3.5f;
        Ray centerRay = _camera.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(.5f, 0.5f, 1f));

        if(Physics.Raycast(_camera.transform.position, theTarget, out _hit, 2.77f) && _hit.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            camOccluded = false;
        }
        if(Physics.Raycast(_camera.transform.position, theTarget, out _hit, 2.77f) && _hit.collider.CompareTag("environment"))
        {
            camOccluded = true;
        }

        /// creates ray from cameraViewPort to nearClipPlane
        float camClipPlane = _camera.nearClipPlane;
        /// sets up clipPoints from camera to viewPort
        Vector3 pos1 = _camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0,0,camClipPlane));   //btmL
        :
        Vector3 pos8 = _camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1,1,camClipPlane));   //topR

        bool clipLine01 = Physics.Linecast(cameraTransform.position, pos1, out _hit, _mask.value);
        :
        bool clipLine08 = Physics.Linecast(cameraTransform.position, pos8, out _hit, _mask.value);

        ///clip conditions are met & camera is occluded
        if((clipLine01)||(clipLine02)||(clipLine03)||(clipLine04)||(clipLine05)||(clipLine06)||(clipLine07)||(clipLine08))
        {
            camOccluded = true;
            //StartCoroutine(ResetCamera());
        }
        else
        {
            camOccluded = false;
        }

        if(!camOccluded)
        {
            Apply (transform, Vector3.zero);//default VCScamera method

        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(ResetCamera());
        }
        print(camOccluded);
        print(headCamTimer);

    }
    public void OverheadCamera()
    {
        Vector3 targetCenter = _target.position + centerOffset;
        Vector3 targetHead = _target.position + headOffset;

        _camera.fieldOfView = fieldOfView;

        cameraTransform.position = (targetHead + cameraOffset) ;
        cameraTransform.LookAt(targetHead);
    }

    IEnumerator ResetCamera()
    {
        //camOccluded = true;
        OverheadCamera();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(headCamTimer);
        _camera.fieldOfView = fovDefault;
        Apply (transform, Vector3.zero);//default VCScamera position
        camOccluded = false;
    }

    public void Cut ( Transform dummyTarget ,   Vector3 dummyCenter  ){
        float oldHeightSmooth= heightSmoothLag;
        float oldSnapMaxSpeed= snapMaxSpeed;
        float oldSnapSmooth= snapSmoothLag;

        snapMaxSpeed = 10000;
        snapSmoothLag = 0.001f;
        heightSmoothLag = 0.001f;

        snap = true;
        Apply (transform, Vector3.zero);

        heightSmoothLag = oldHeightSmooth;
        snapMaxSpeed = oldSnapMaxSpeed;
        snapSmoothLag = oldSnapSmooth;
    }

    public void SetUpRotation (Vector3 centerPos,  Vector3 headPos)
    {
        // Now it's getting hairy. The devil is in the details here, the big issue is jumping of course.
        // * When jumping up and down we don't want to center the guy in screen space.
        //  This is important to give a feel for how high you jump and avoiding large camera movements.
        //   
        // * At the same time we dont want him to ever go out of screen and we want all rotations to be totally smooth.
        //
        // So here is what we will do:
        //
        // 1. We first find the rotation around the y axis. Thus he is always centered on the y-axis
        // 2. When grounded we make him be centered
        // 3. When jumping we keep the camera rotation but rotate the camera to get him back into view if his head is above some threshold
        // 4. When landing we smoothly interpolate towards centering him on screen

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------//

        _camera.fieldOfView = fovDefault; // defaults camera to desired FOV

        Vector3 cameraPos = cameraTransform.position;
        Vector3 offsetToCenter= centerPos - cameraPos;

        // Generate base rotation only around y-axis
        Quaternion yRotation= Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(offsetToCenter.x, 0, offsetToCenter.z));

        Vector3 relativeOffset= Vector3.forward * distance + Vector3.down * height;
        cameraTransform.rotation = yRotation * Quaternion.LookRotation(relativeOffset);

        // Calculate the projected center position and top position in world space
        Ray centerRay = _camera.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(.5f, 0.5f, 1f));
        Ray topRay = _camera.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(.5f, clampHeadPositionScreenSpace, 1f));

        Vector3 centerRayPos= centerRay.GetPoint(distance);
        Vector3 topRayPos= topRay.GetPoint(distance);

        float centerToTopAngle= Vector3.Angle(centerRay.direction, topRay.direction);

        float heightToAngle= centerToTopAngle / (centerRayPos.y - topRayPos.y);

        float extraLookAngle= heightToAngle * (centerRayPos.y - centerPos.y);
        if (extraLookAngle < centerToTopAngle)
        {
            extraLookAngle = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            extraLookAngle = extraLookAngle - centerToTopAngle;
            cameraTransform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(-extraLookAngle, 0, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every `fixedUpdate`, perform a [`Raycast`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) from the player to the standard location of the camera where the maxDistance is the distance between player and standard location. When it hits a mesh, move the camera to the hit location. When it doesn't, move the camera to its standard location.

That way the camera will automatically move in and out based on the geometry ensuring that the player has a clear view on their character. A requirement for this is that everything which might obstruct the camera must have a Collider component which is at least as large as the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

Found an easier solution by using volume colliders which which can be set up as zones for overhead cameras.

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider thePlayer)
{
    if (thePlayer.gameObject.CompareTag ("headCamZone"))
    {
        OverheadCamera();
    }
    //followCamZone
    if (thePlayer.gameObject.CompareTag ("followCamZone"))
    {
        Apply (transform, Vector3.zero);//default VCScamera method
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what this solution is doing, but I'm curious. Can you explain more?

Comment: I've essentially created zones using colliders. For instance, when the player walks inside "headCamZone", the camera moves overhead & disables the orbit functionality (causes clipping issues) that comes with this plug-in's touch input/camera system from the asset store. This solution also allows me to move the camera to any position depending on predefined zones just by changing Vector3 variables. Others use sphere rigidBodies around the camera- then write lines of code to compensate for the physics associated with it...I didn't have to do all that.

Comment: so this approach requires you to define headCamZone triggers near all walls in the level?

Comment: I suppose you could if you wanted to. I don't think it's necessary or foresee myself doing that. For example, your in a 512*512 area- it's large enough for the camera to orbit around the player but small enough that objects in that area will get in the way of the camera & player. I would just place 2 zones there- placing the camera in optimal positions.